# Combination of models classes. Editing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have

- [D]Controllers

  - AdmController.cs
- [D]Models

  - [D]_products

    - ASUS.cs
    - MAC.cs
    - ...etc...
  - [D]note_ASUS

    - asus_cpu.cs
    - asus_memory.cs
    - ...etc...
  - [D]note_MAC

    - mac_cpu.cs
    - mac_memory.cs
    - ...etc...
- [D]View

  - [D]Adm

    - Edit.cs
    - ...other...

**ASUS.cs**

```
namespace Store.Models._products
{
    public class ASUS
    {
        public virtual note_ASUS.asus_cpu class_cpu { get; set; }
        public virtual note_ASUS.asus_memory class_memory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**asus_cpu.cs**

```
namespace Store.Models.note_ASUS
{
    public class asus_cpu
    {
        [Key]
        public int CpuID { get; set; }
        public string CpuName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**asus_memory.cs**

```
namespace Store.Models.note_ASUS
{
    public class asus_memory
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemoryID { get; set; }
        public string MemoryName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View - **Edit.cs**

```
@model Store.Models._products.ASUS

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**I do not work for me edit box prices.**

How to modify the code to work?
Do you need only change a line `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)`
I tried `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.class_cpu.Price)` which also does not work.

My task is to add the edit panel to the properties of the product. Name, price etc...
As another way to get?

PS:

```
@model Store.Models.note_ASUS.asus_cpu

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

returns -

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_2B11F5A3B582AEEDC3A227AC890AB303622EA53BAA68892797896468D341A905',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Store.Models.note_ASUS.asus_cpu'.

Comment: Actually `model.Price` does not exist, so it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I would like to make a model so that I will be able to refer to individual files `asus_cpu, asus_memory, etc ... and it` edit `Edit.cshtml`

Comment: My task is to add the edit panel to the properties of the product. Name, price etc. ..

Comment: Have you tried `Html.EditorFor(model => model.class_cpu)`? Or maybe even `Html.EditorFor(model => model)`?

Comment: *How to modify the code to work?* - In what way doesn't it work? All you've done is dump your code in the post and said "it's broke."

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work

Comment: @AntP It seemed to me that this is enough. What specific information do you need?

Comment: @user3128303 If you walked into a garage and said "my car doesn't work," do you not think that the mechanic would require a bit more information? The first thing they're going to ask is "what's wrong with it?" You wouldn't expect them to go and thoroughly inspect your entire car with no description of the problem.

Comment: you're right. I made the edition.

Comment: @AntP Do you have any idea to solve the problem of editing?